# Is "Inheritance as Specialization" hurt? And how can it be fixed?

Tags: design-principles

**Given is the following package/class diagram of an implementation of java.util.List:**

[image: Package/Class Diagram of java.util.List 1]

***1. Which design principle is (most likely) hurt by the ArrayBasedList class?***

The design principle that is hurt by the `ArrayBasedList` class is the "**Use inheritance as a Specialization**" because the `ArrayBasedList` **is** (extends) a List that **uses** the `ArrayUtilities`. This principle is hurt, as inheritance should not be used for "usage" properties.

In addition, multiple inheritance is not supported by Java.

***2. What would be the preferred way to model this situation in a correct way (as UML)?***

The preferred way to model this situation in a correct way using UML will be to make the `ArrayBasedList` implement the `List` interface and **use** the `ArrayUtilites`.

In code this would be translated in:

```
package app.list;
import app.util;

public class ArrayBasedList implements List {
    
    private ArrayUtilities util = new ArrayUtilities ();
    public ArrayBasedList(){
    
    }
}
```

And in UML in this:

[image]

My solution was based on [How should I have explained the difference between an Interface and an Abstract class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18777989/how-should-i-have-explained-the-difference-between-an-interface-and-an-abstract/34978606#34978606)

What do you think about my approach?

**Edit 13/01/2021:** This question was part of an examination sheet in a Software related master program. I can understand that the question perhaps is a bit abstract but at the same time, after reading carefully the comment/response, I do realize that my solution approach seems to heading in the right direction.

**Edit 31/01/2021:** After a discussion with a Professor who teaches System Design at a Software related master program, I reliased that the optimal solution to this problem wouldn't "convert" arbitrarily the `ArrayUtilities` from a **class** to an **interface**. As a result, I changed the relationship between the `ArrayBasedList` and the `ArrayUtilities` as shown above.

Comment: "Which design principle is (most likely) hurt by the ArrayBasedList class?" - there's literally not enough information to provide a meaningful answer. The design principle is not hurt "because the ArrayBasedList is not only an Array but it has the methods from List and ArrayUtilites as well", this, in itself, doesn't necessarily matter. Using only interface inheritance ("implements") does *potentially* make the code more decoupled - *if you've done it for a good reason*. Whether or not this is a good thing depends on if what you gain by decoupling outweighs the costs that it brings.

Comment: In other words, it's not about diagrams and following abstract rules without having an idea of what the components depicted in the diagrams represent, and how they are supposed to work together. Design principles, even though general in formulation, need to be understood in the context of a problem (you can't make sense of them in terms of an abstract diagram that doesn't specify what the design-relevant features of the model are). And specific designs that can be deemed right (or wrong) are problem-specific. That's the whole point of design - you're using it to tackle a specific problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The principle being violated here is often phrased as **favor composition over inheritance**. You seem to have correctly identified the principle, but not how to follow it.

`ArrayBasedList` should neither inherit from nor implement `ArrayUtilities`. Instead, it should encapsulate an implementation of `ArrayUtilities`. In other words, a *has-a* relationship instead of an *is-a* relationship.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt and interesting response. What seems difficult for me to understand, is how can the encapsulation of an implementation of `ArrayUtilities` described in the UML diagram.

Comment: @KonstantinosLoizas It generally wouldn't be, because it's an implementation detail.

Comment: @KonstantinosLoizas I have no idea what professors think. I just know I've made a career out of cleaning up after people with degrees.

Comment: I've always head it as [favor composition over inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance#:~:text=To%20favor%20composition%20over%20inheritance,and%20creating%20a%20family%20tree.). I've never heard of favor encapsulation over inheritance. Do you have a reference to this?

Comment: @candied_orange Quite right. Composition is the design goal; encapsulation is the mechanism.